# raw socket communication between two applications one in c and one in java

Tags: java, c, raw-sockets

I have a application (acting as the server) written in `c` that is listening on a raw socket, with this socket descriptor: `socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_RAW, 0);`. The 0 indicates `IPPROTO_IP`

I want to write a code in java (acting as the client) to send an ip packet to this raw socket that is listening. Now i read around that java needs a 3rd party library to manage raw sockets. People recommend `junixsocket` and `juds` so i'll use one of them i guess.

Junixsocket does something like this to define a raw socket:

```
File socketFile = new File("/path/to/your/socket");
AFUNIXSocket sock = AFUNIXSocket.newInstance();
sock.connect(new AFUNIXSocketAddress(socketFile));
```

So the question is:

Is it possible to make these 2 applications communicate with eachother through this raw socket? In java you need to establish the socketfilename and path whereas in c thats not compulsory. My c code does not specify a socketfilename or path so i dont know how to make them communicate on the same socket. How do i make sure they're both sending/receiving on the same raw socket? All this communication is happening only in local!

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by socketfilename ? do you mean URL , like `localhost:8080` or `ip-address:port` that is required to create a socket client.

Comment: i edited the question to answer your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the unix domain sockets (`AF_UNIX`). They are effectively designed for processes running on the same kernel, and use *filesystem pathnames for addressing* (see `man 4 unix` for details). So you have to share a pathname between both processes.

Edit as requested:

To set up the unix domain socket in C app, you need an address of type `sockaddr_un`, and fill up its `sun_path` member with a path to your socket:

```
    sockaddr_un sockaddr;
    memset(&sockaddr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr));
    sockaddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(sockaddr.sun_path, "/path/to/your/socket", UNIX_MAX_PATH);
```

and either `bind()` or `connect()` your socket to this `sockaddr`.

<s>However, it has nothing to do with `SOCK_RAW`. Correct me if I am wrong, but you want a raw socket over the Internet, that is `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 0)`.</s>

Comment: No no, i dont want the raw socket over the internet. I want it in local on the same machine. Can you please show me an example of how to define both sockets on the same filesystem pathnames for addressing?